# Firefox 71 Developer Tools can't edit the DOM

Tags: firefox

I've noticed a very strange change in Firefox 71. In Firefox 70, you could edit html node properties directly, by `Right click`>`Inspect Element`>`Double click on the element to edit`. This was most useful for websites that lack a "peek" option for the password and have draconian policies for getting it wrong, as I could change `type="password"` to `type="text"` and verify if I've typed my password correctly.

However, in Firefox 71 this no longer appears possible. Using `Del` and `Backspace` while having an HTML node selected in the Developer Tools will instead delete the previous/next node. Is there a configurable setting to restore the previous mode, or should I report this as a bug? Do other people experience the same issue?

Comment: you can right click > inspect element > right click in inspector > select "Edit HT,ML", assuming you have same language settings etc. as I do of course.

Comment: That works, but it's much slower - I need to 1.right click, 2.move the mouse up to select `Edit as HTML`, 3. click it, 4. edit, 5. move the mouse, 6. click outside the node. Previously i could 1. double click, which would select the full text inside the quotes, 2. write the new value and 3. press `Enter`

Comment: I believe after your edit you can get out of the edited node by pressing the escape key, can't confirm right now as I am at a place where firefox is not allowed